# There is a problem in the loop and the second loop does not work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need a second loop to do something, but no matter what I try, I don't get the desired result :(

code:

```
@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print("Client is online!")
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name="UwU"))
    try:
        synced = await client.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} command(s)")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    while True:
        await print("is online! 1")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await print("is online! 2")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await print("is online! 3")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)

    while True:
        await print("ready 1")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await print("ready  2")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        await print("ready  3")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
```

Comment: You have an infinite first loop, so how could you ever reach the second one?

Comment: Because I want both loops to be infinite

If you know a better way, please share it with me

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with an infinite loop?

Comment: Repeat, repeat, repeat until it shuts off!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is doing *exactly* what you have written it to do.

`while True:` will execute everything in the loop *forever* until `True` is not `True` or until you `break` out of the loop. If you want to have two loops running simultaneously, we'll have to find another way of running them.

The first option is to use the `asyncio` library to create tasks.

```py
async def online_loop():
    while True:
        print("is online")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)

async def ready_loop():
    while True:
        print("is ready")
        await asyncio.sleep(3)


# and then in your on_ready function
@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    asyncio.create_task(online_loop())
    asyncio.create_task(ready_loop())
```

The second option, is to use the [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html) functionality built in to `discord.py`. A very basic implementation would be:

```py
# with your imports
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=3.0)
async def forever_print():
    print("is online and ready")

@forever_print.before_loop
async def before_print(self):
    print('waiting...')
    await client.wait_until_ready()

# then in on_ready
async def on_ready():
   forever_print.start()
```

Again, this is a basic tasks implementation; the docs have more (and better!) examples of how to use them.

Although, I don't *really* recommend just using loops/tasks just to continuously print something. I like to keep a cleaner log and save printing/logging stuff to console/log file for important messages or debug information rather than just continuously printing that the bot is online/ready every few seconds.